# How to programmatically check if the terminal supports italics?

Tags: terminal, console, terminal-emulator

I'd like to check if the current terminal is able to display italics correctly.

Checking that manually is easy:

```
echo -e "\e[3mfoo\e[23m"
```

If the output is *`foo`*, the terminal (emulator) supports italics.
However, I'd like to test in my `.zshrc` if italics are supported programmatically.

What is the best practice to do that?

---

If (at all) possible, I'd like my standard Linux console to be able to use italics as well. Problem is, the manual test fails, any ideas how to make italics possible in there?

*(this is not part of the original question. It's too vague and meaningless to ask as a stand-alone question, though.)*

Answer (score 4):

That's several questions:

- If the Linux console supported italics, that would use a different font or use some technique such as slanting the characters to imitate italics.
- Assuming it did that, you would need a tool that can dump the image of what's displayed on the console to see this in a program.  But the Linux console screen dumps give only text — no images.  There is no font information available in the dump (not even bold or color).
- Both `setterm` and `screendump` open the raw `vcsa` device (though `screendump` as an alternative uses the the default for the `TIOCLINUX` ioctl, which has the same content)
- You *could* write a suitable tool to dump attributes such as color and whether bold was used, with this obsolete ioctl (i.e., your kernel is very old):

  > **`TIOCLINUX`**, subcode=**8**
  >   Dump screen width and height, cursor position, and all the character-attribute  pairs.   (Kernels  **1.1.67**  through **1.1.91** only.
  >   With kernel 1.1.92 or later, read from /dev/vcsa* instead.)
- In short, there's no supported mechanism for finding what's on the screen of the Linux console.

Besides there being no solution to *programmatically* determining if italics are implemented, aside from using some special feature to increase resolution, there's little reason to expect that Linux console fonts will be drawn in italics.  The [Terminus font page](http://terminus-font.sourceforge.net/) (which is relevant, since it tries to give the same effect in X as the Linux console fonts) says this in its *Frequently Asked Questions* section:

> Q. Italic version?
>
> A. No. The quality is significantly lower, and preserving the font width requires overlapping characters, which are not handled very well by X11/Xft. Anyway, the modern GUIs support automatic slanting; if you are not satisfied with it, try mkitalic from FreeBSD or bdfslant from Debian.
>
> Q. Scalable version?
>
> A. Long story short, when the average display resolution becomes at least 150 DPI. Prefferably 200.

Further reading:

- [The Linux keyboard and console HOWTO: 20. Screen dumps](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Keyboard-and-Console-HOWTO-20.html)
- [screendump - dump the contents of a virtual console to stdout](http://www.unix.com/man-page/linux/1/screendump/)
- [KBD – Linux keyboard tools](http://kbd-project.org/) (provides `screendump`)
- [util-linux/util-linux.git](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/utils/util-linux/util-linux.git/) (provides `setterm`)
- [console_ioctl - ioctls for console terminal and virtual consoles](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man4/console_ioctl.4.html)

Answer (score 3):

It's not possible to reliably test whether the terminal actually supports italics. You can, by checking the output of `tput sitm` or `tput ritm`, test whether the value of `$TERM` and its corresponding terminal description *claims* to support it – but the claim and the actual behavior might easily be out of sync in either direction.

I really doubt the Linux console supports or will support italics in the foreseeable future.